# How to have two input adornments in Material UI next to each other in a text field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I went over the Text Field demo where they show input adornments at the start and end but I want two input adornments at the end and I tried to do have endAdornment: {InputAdornment InputAdornment} but then I got an error saying adjacent JSX elements must have a parent element. Then I used a div tag but then I got an error saying that my brackets were misplaced.
This is how I want the input adornments to be

[image]

Comment: Please show your current code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting to look like?
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-trbit?file=/demo.tsx:1640-2360

[image]

```
    <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin} variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-amount">Amount</InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id="outlined-adornment-amount"
        value={values.amount}
        onChange={handleChange("amount")}
        startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
        endAdornment={
          <>
            <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
            <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
            <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
          </>
        }
        labelWidth={60}
      />
    </FormControl>
```